# Why isn't splice working in this for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

```
var arr = ['apples','oranges','pears','grapes'];

for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] == 'pears') {
    arr.splice(i,0,'limes');
  }
}
```

When I try to run this in jsfiddle, the page freezes. jsfiddle also freezes if I use a specific index in place of i (`arr.splice(2,0,'limes')`) or if I try to remove items (`arr.splice(2,1)`). If I do this without the for loop and instead choose a specific index, it will work. What's wrong here? Is there any way I can make splice work (for adding, not removing items) inside a for loop?

Also, when I use FreeCodeCamp's editor with this code, it does not freeze but it gives me back the original array as if splice was never used on it. If I assign a variable to it (`var rem = arr.splice(i,1)` in a for loop), however, it returns the removed items without actually modifying the array itself (the array remains exactly the same).

Comment: Is there a custom function for `splice` in the array prototype?

Comment: `arr.splice(i++, 0, 'limes');` <-- post-increment `i` so that when the matched item gets pushed forward, the next iteration of the loop doesn't encounter it.

Comment: Try: `arr.splice(arr.indexOf('pears'), 0, 'limes');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arr.splice(i,0,'limes');
```

will inject 'limes' element *before* the 'pears' element, 
effectively shifting it one position towards the end of array,
so on the next iteration your code will hit 'pears' once again,
and inject one more 'limes' in front of it and so on.

You can easily visualize this by adding

```
console.log(arr);
```

after your if block, which will result in the output like this:

```
    ["apples", "oranges", "limes", "pears", "grapes"]
    ["apples", "oranges", "limes", "limes", "pears", "grapes"]
    ["apples", "oranges", "limes", "limes", "limes", "pears", "grapes"]
    ["apples", "oranges", "limes", "limes", "limes", "limes", "pears","grapes"]
    ...
```

Comment: I tried adding the console.log function, but in jsfiddle it freezes and I never get to see the output. FreeCodeCamp's editor will give me the original array instead of the modified one. I suppose this is how they avoid infinite loop problems. Thanks for the visualization though. If I had seen that in the console, I would have been able to figure out what was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite loop. You are adding a new element before the pears instead of removing it. so the next iteration will give you pears again. If that's your intention just add a break statement. If you want to replace the element pear you can use the following function.

> From MDN
>
> array.splice(start, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]])

You can see that you are not deleting anything but adding a new element before at index i (i.e before pears).

```js
var arr = ['apples','oranges','pears','grapes'];

for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] == 'pears') {
    arr.splice(i,1,'limes');
 
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Could you explain what the changed code does differently (I know, but I'm guessing the OP doesn't)?

Comment: The pears would now be removed...and lime will be added to the array

Comment: "Is there any way I can make splice work (**for adding**, not removing items) inside a for loop"

Comment: Yup just add break inside your loop if u beleive there would be just one 'pears' else instead of increment i

Comment: @Andreas absolutely ! Just use break statement. It all depends on your condition but you can do al kinda crazy stuff with splice.

Comment: That's the question of the OP. Your solution replaces `"pears"` with `"limes"` instead of adding it

Comment: I have added that in the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This is how `for` loops work :

```
for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++);
```

`i=0;` initialize `i` with `0`;  Then, at the beginning of every iteration check this condition `i < arr.length` if it's `true` perform next iteration, otherwise leave the loop. At the end of each iteration `i++` increments `i`.

Since `arr.splice(i,0,'limes')` alter the array and add an element at position `i`, it will push the value `pears` to the next index. Thus, `if (arr[i] == 'pears')` will be always `true` and this condition `i < arr.length` will never be `false`: **Endless `for` ...**