# How to remove multiple object from an array in angular 13

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, angular13

Tried to delete multiple object from an array by selecting the checkbox table row. But in my code only 1 item is deleted. Not able to delete multiple selection object. How to resolve this issue?

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fflhjh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

app.component.ts:

```
  removeSelectedRow() { 
    this.data2.forEach((value, index) => {
      console.log(value);
      if (value.isSelected === true) {
        this.data2.splice(index, 1);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: `splice` won't work in a `forEach` loop, since every time you splice, you affect the `index`es of the undeleted items (see [Why isn't splice working in this for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38413999/215552)). Instead, `reduce` or `filter` your array to a new array without the items.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: Can you update your answer in the stackblitz?

Comment: I don't have an answer. I made two comments. One with a reason why it wasn't working and a suggestion, a second pointing to a question that asks essentially the same question. I'm not going to apply the duplicate's answers to your problem. Do that yourself. If you are unable to, ask a new question showing what you tried and the errors you get when you do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.filter` and `Array.Includes` archieve the result you need.
Refer the below code for more reference:

```js
let items = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Item 1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Item 2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Item 3' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Item 4' },
  { id: 5, name: 'Item 5' }
];


const itemsToRemove = [2, 4]; // Array of item IDs to be removed


items = items.filter(item => !itemsToRemove.includes(item.id));

console.log(items);
```